# Applying filters to model which is not part of query in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to apply filters which reference fields in a lazy loaded model. 
However i do not want this model as part of the returned result.
e.g.

```
query = context.session.query(modelA).options(joinedload(
            'column_for_model_B').joinedload(
                'column_for_model_C', innerjoin=True))
filtered_query = apply_filters(query, filter)

Filter can be soemthing like
  {'and': [(eq,modelA.field1,'value1'),(eq,modelC.field1,'value2')]}
```

For above code bad specification error is thrown.

If ModelC is part of query clause,the filter can be applied without problem
Like below

```
context.session.query(modelA,modelC)...
```

I want to apply filters on ModelC without having to return ModelC fields.
Just ModelA . Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to filter using a lazy loaded join/relation you can use the [contains_eager](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result) option.

Continue reading to [Advanced Usage with Arbitrary Statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#advanced-usage-with-arbitrary-statements) find how you could use select statements to exclude the relation/collection from the results.

Comment: The title was incorrect. I have changed it. This answer does not help me, as i described i need to apply filters on ModelC without it being returned.